# speeding up routine with eight nested for loops in any way possible

Tags: python, numpy, loops, iteration, numba

I have a function, `_get_result`, which takes in shape (`L` , `L`) np.complex64 arrays `B`, `evec`, `f_mat`, a shape (`L`) np.complex64 array `ener`, and other `float32`s, and returns some `np.complex64`.

Currently, it goes through 8-for loops. For each loop, it constructs matrices depending on the looping indices via `_get_elements`, then calculates permanent of these matrices by `_perm`.

As you might imagine for an 8-for loop routine, it is painfully slow. I'd like to have a code to goes to L ~ 64 in a reasonable computation time (less than say, a couple days), but even after using numba to accelerate the code, already at L = 4, it takes ~ 1 sec, L = 8 ~ 200 sec, and L = 16 ~ 3 hrs, so I don't think it will scale well in this state.

(I know that permanents of matrices scale O(eⁿ), but I am calculating permanents of quite small matrices (4x4 at maximum), so I don't think that's the problem.)

Is there a way to speed up this code using any method? I'm wondering if I made any of the for-loops redundantly, or I could calculate these quantities any faster, or if there's anything I can do with parallelisation, utilising GPUs, or anything else.

Below is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

dtype_complex = np.complex64

@njit
def _perm(matrix):
    n = matrix.shape[0]
    d = np.ones(n, dtype=dtype_complex)
    j =  0
    s = 1
    f = np.arange(n)
    v = matrix.sum(axis=0)
    p = np.prod(v)
    while (j < n - 1):
        v -= 2 * d[j]*matrix[j]
        d[j] = -d[j]
        s = -s
        prod = np.prod(v)
        p += s * prod
        f[0] = 0
        f[j] = f[j+1]
        f[j+1] = j + 1
        j = f[0]
    return p / 2 ** (n - 1)

@njit
def _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, lefts, rights):
    length = len(lefts)
    to_perm = np.zeros((length, length), dtype=dtype_complex)

    for idx1, lbit_idx1 in enumerate(lefts):
        for idx2, lbit_idx2 in enumerate(rights):
            to_perm[idx1, idx2] = one_over_det * matrix[lbit_idx2, lbit_idx1]
    return _perm(to_perm)

@njit
def _get_result(t, L, B, ener, evec, f_mat, I, site1, site2):

    result = 0.0 + 0.0j
    for a in np.arange(L):
        for b in np.arange(L):
            for e in np.arange(L):
                for f in np.arange(L):
                    H_abef = 2 * (B[:,a] - B[:,b] + B[:,e] - B[:,f])

                    f_exp_H_abef_t = f_mat @ (np.diag(np.exp(1j * H_abef * t)).astype(dtype_complex))

                    to_inv = I + f_mat - f_exp_H_abef_t
                    inv = np.linalg.inv(to_inv)

                    one_over_det = 1.0 / np.linalg.det(to_inv)
                    matrix = f_exp_H_abef_t @ inv

                    phase1 = np.exp(1j * (
                        ener[a] - ener[b] + ener[e] - ener[f]
                        - B[a, a] - B[b, b] - B[e, e] - B[f, f]
                        + 2 * (
                            + B[a, b] + B[e, f]
                            + B[f, a] + B[f, b]
                            - B[e, a] - B[e, b]
                        )
                    ) * t)

                    for c in np.arange(L):
                        for d in np.arange(L):

                            phase2 = np.exp(2j * (
                                B[f, c] + B[f, d] - B[e, c] - B[e, d]
                            ) * t)

                            for g in np.arange(L):
                                for h in np.arange(L):

                                    # 8th order term
                                    elements = _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c, e, g], [b, d, f, h])

                                    # 6th order terms
                                    if b == c: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, e, g], [d, f, h])

                                    if d == e: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c, g], [b, f, h])

                                    if b == e: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c, g], [d, f, h])

                                    if f == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c, e], [b, d, h])

                                    if d == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c, e], [b, f, h])

                                    if b == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c, e], [d, f, h])

                                    # quartic terms
                                    if b == e and f == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c], [d, h])

                                    if b == e and d == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c], [f, h])

                                    if b == c and f == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, e], [d, h])

                                    if b == c and d == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c], [f, h])

                                    if d == e and f == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c], [b, h])

                                    if b == c and d == e: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, g], [f, h])

                                    if d == e and b == g: elements += _get_elements(one_over_det, matrix, [a, c], [f, h])

                                    # quadratic term
                                    if b == c and d == e and f == g: elements += one_over_det * matrix[h, a]

                                    unitary = evec[site2, a] * evec[site2, b] \
                                            * evec[site1, c] * evec[site1, d] \
                                            * evec[site2, e] * evec[site2, f] \
                                            * evec[site1, g] * evec[site1, h]
                                    
                                    result += unitary * phase1 * phase2 * elements
    
    return result
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did not go through all your requirements, why not reshape your data to as many dimensions as per your nested loops and vectorize your operations.

Comment: I think the problem there would be, because there are 8-nested for-loops, I would need to reshape into (L, L, L, L, L, L, L, L)-shaped arrays, right? which I don't think would fit on any ram. I guess I could do partial vectorisation - could you possibly point out where you think vectorisation could work?

Comment: Sorry, I did not properly look at your code. What about using the numba library of writing a cython function. A more radical option (that is highly dependant on your ecosystem) would be to use Julia Programming Language that is designed to handle exactly this kind of problem and runs as close to C speed.